# How can I install CentOS on the Windows Intel Compute Stick

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, centos, intel-atom

Intel Compute Stick comes in two versions: one with Windows 8.1 and one with Ubuntu, but the Linux version has half the RAM and far less internal storage and nearly impossible to buy.

So I am trying to install Linux on the "Windows" Compute Stick.  I am using CentOS rather than Ubuntu, but my problem is that CentOS can only be installed (as far as I know) by booting from an alternate drive holding an ISO image of the OS (one can then install the image on an internal drive.  The Compute Stick has no external drives, so I have tried:

1. installing a SD card giving me a drive D
2. attaching a USB memory stick
3. attaching a USB DVD drive

But when I boot the BIOS it still offers me only the internal drive C option.  If I go to the BIOS menu to change the order of drives used for booting it still shows only the internal drive.

Does anyone know of a way to get the BIOS in the Compute Stick to allow booting from any external device?  Or any other way to install CentOS?

I have never installed Ubuntu.  Does it offer other ways to install?

I do not need to install it as dual boot, I am happy to commit the internal drive to Linux only but cannot see how to do this.

Comment: If I change the OS Type in the BIOS to Ubuntu and put an OS iso on a USB stick then it IS recognized. My problem was apparently not having the OS in ISO form on the USB stick and USB DVD not recognized.  I tried with CentOS 6.6 and it boots but neither a wireless or USB keyboard was recognized so I could not follow the install menus.  Is there a driver missing?  I retried with Ubuntu 14.10 and it appears to work fine.  I would still be interested in how CentOS could be used if anyone knows more about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu installs fine, if set as an iso on a USB stick and OS is set to Ubuntu in BIOS.  The 14.10 version I tried hung randomly before completing install so after 5 tries I used 14.04.2 and that is working fine.

I would still like to know how to get CentOS to recognize USB keyboard/mouse but I can live with Ubuntu.